# curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated

Tags: installation, rabbitmq, erlang, rpm, ca

rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server                                                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:02
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server':

- Curl error (60): Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for https://d28dx6y1hfq314.cloudfront.net/828/1033/el/8/x86_64/repodata/4ee7275d09a30b8e41895ab1378340119350d9e47d3aeee8303feaea31ebb1af-repomd.xml?t=1689765546_fbb972f09e89f6abe351d81b70b2c3484ad458fb [SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain]

rabbitmq_rabbitmq-server   on rocky